Global Proxy setting for ubutnu 24.04 LTS
is there any way to setup global proxy settings in ubuntu 24 ? . it's so ridiculous that you setup proxy in settings and no application use it except browsers :) .
can somebody help me please ?
just set the proxy settings in ubuntu gui and it does not work for all applications .
I don't know what to do with wine and metatrader5 . I'm in Iran and I have limitations with network .
and currently even with setting up a proxy server on ubuntu , the metatrader does not respect these settings . and even If i put settings in tools > options > server > proxy settings
it won't work too . this ubuntu is making me sick . lack of simple settings , bugs , and so on .

I haven't had to use a proxy, but I think it shouldn't be much different from VPN settings. If you configure OpenVPN through the Ubuntu graphical interface or run the configuration file from the terminal, it affects the entire system (browsers, connecting to servers via ssh, etc.). There is a possibility that the proxy itself proxies traffic only to certain resources, and sends it directly to all others.
